# Is there a book only about epsilon delta proofs?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, epsilon-delta

I want to know if there is such book, with beautiful epsilon delta proofs of all kind.

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Analysis-AMS-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/082182693X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1408068053&sr=8-1&keywords=foundations+of+analysis+edmund) and [this](http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Integral-Calculus-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821828304/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=18FRXX88NWTTWJTGWFK7) may fit the bill.

Comment: It would be a very short book.

Comment: In analytic number theory and elsewhere, there are wonderful theorems based on extremely delicate estimates. But I would not classify these as $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs in the usual sense.

Comment: A great book is Calculus by Spivak.

Comment: I'm giving this question a +1 just for the sheer audacity of asking for *more* epsilon-delta proofs after (I presume) sitting through some calculus courses

Comment: @YuriyS I wanted to be ready for all possible epsilon delta proofs my teacher could ask on the test lol

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, that must be a good teacher, because mine never asked for more or less than his lecture material

Comment: One can only take the lack of answers as a sign that such an object does not exist

Answer (score 1):

- Introduction to Analysis by Maxwell Rosenlicht
- Foundations of Analysis by Edmund Landau
- Advanced Calculus by Avner Friedman